# jQuery click target selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML in a page:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="move-next"><img src="/Content/images/small-next-arrow.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Next status arrow" title="Progress to next status"/></a></div>
```

and I have the following javascript that attempts to handle the click event:

```
function InitProgressionSelectors() {
$(".move-next").click(function() {
    moveNext(this);
});

$(".move-previous").click(function() {
    movePrevious(this);
});
}

function moveNext(target) {
    var sourceContainer = target.parent("td");
    var targetContainer = sourceContainer.next("td");
}
```

I'm obviously missing something, because "target" in the moveNext function is returning an HTMLAnchorElement, but when I try to wrap that, or access it somehow as a jQuery object, so I can try to get a handle to it's parent container, I get errors.

A reference to $(target) returns null. How do I get a reference to target as a jQuery object so I can work with it in that context? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a demo that reproduces your problem at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: idon't remeber whether parent and next belongs to jquery api or regular javascript , right now you are just passing this and using this.parent , if you want to use jquery , you need to use $(this).parent ///

Comment: Wow...I'm an idiot. @gov - You were right, I needed to be passing $(this), not just "this". That got me where I needed to be. Thanks.

Comment: you can give a vote , if you like my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments below, using $(target) didn't work. However, as can be seen in the comments on the original question above, the solution was to actually pass `$(this)` as the argument. Once I did that, `target.parent` resolved to the expected node, and worked.

---

bob can you try using dollor

$(target)

```
var sourceContainer = $(target).parent("td");
```

Comment: "A reference to $(target) returns null" ...so, $(target).parent("td") returns an error.

Comment: @bob can you do a alert before calling the function do a alert(this) , it should print object object///otherwise you have to post the html in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

You need pass the jquery object

```
$(".move-previous").click(function() {
    movePrevious($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to pass the function in by reference:

```
$(".move-next").click(moveNext);
```

You can then use the selector as expected:

```
function moveNext() {
    var sourceContainer = $(this).parent("td");
    var targetContainer = sourceContainer.next("td");
}
```

Please note the lack of parentheses when passing the function to the click handler.